what can be added to a provisional patent when the non-provisional is filed?
I have a list of workarounds to my invention not specified in a provisional application.
When the non-provisional application is filed, would I be able to add the list of workarounds to the applications?
If not, what can be added to what is already there in a provisional application when the non-provisional is filed?

What do you mean by work-arounds?

slight modifications of the main idea of the invention. Essentially it is additional embodiments that I want to disclose so that I can include them in the claims as well

A non-provisional application claiming the benefit of a provisional application should be as comprehensive an application as possible, including whatever you think would help valuable claims be allowed and stand up later if challenged.
Anything not well supported by the provisional application will not get the benefit of the priority date of the provisional but don’t leave something out for that reason unless you know some intervening prior art makes the additional claim scope anticipated (not novel).
